# PHP fread catch stream timeout happened

Tags: php, php-stream-wrappers

I use the PHP function fread to read the data from a stream opened with

```
$fh=fopen('http://.....');
```

i set the timeout for the stream with

```
socket_set_timeout($fh,10);
```

if a timeout happened during the fread execution then can i somehow to know about this?

```
$contents = fread($fh, 1024);
```

if timeout happens then will $contents be equal empty string or FALSE ? how to know that timeout happened? is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc page for that function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php):

> When the stream times out, the 'timed_out' key of the array returned
> by stream_get_meta_data() is set to TRUE, although no error/warning is
> generated.

So there are no errors/warnings generated, but inspecting the output from `stream_get_meta_data` will give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

fread() will return `''` (empty string) when a timeout occurs unlike `socket_read()` which returns `false`.